# Access (Point to site) Azure VPN from non windows OS

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-network

Currently I am designing a solution for connecting Smart devices that are hosted behind a Router using NAT. The Central service etc are hosted on Azure. One idea is to join all devices and the Azure components in a VPN using the Point to Site solution. The smart devices do not have a Windows based operating system. In the portal the configuration for the Windows standard VPN client is available. I now would like to find out if it is posible to Connect to the Azure VPN using other clients and so how to configurate these(Setting the GateWay, attachint the client cetificate etc.)

Comment: What is OS of your devices? Azure point-to-site VPN uses SSTP (secure socket tunnelling protocol). Search for a SSTP VPN client for your OS.

Comment: I have had a tip OpenSwan is a possible client

Comment: Have you done it? I'm trying to setup openswan for point-to-site VPN, where collaborators from several different locations need to connect to Azure Virtual Network.

Answer (score 0):

If your client architecture permit it, you may put in place on the client side a Windows (or Linux) machine having a gateway role. You will either:

- connect this machine to Azure via Point-to-Site SSTP VPN and expose a service acting as proxy from the cloud service to the local devices
- use Azure IoT Gateway SDK for all this: https://azure.microsoft.com/fr-fr/blog/introducing-the-azure-iot-gateway-sdk-beta/

In any case this architecture is more robust. But works only if it possible from your client architecture point of view.